# Stuck in dependent drop down menu

Tags: node.js, reactjs, drop-down-menu, frontend

I got stuck while creating a dependent drop down menu in react. I am trying to make a form in which user can select three options through the drop down menu respectively and based on the options selected the 4th field which is a disabled text field will be populated with the appropriate result.

This is my code.

```
        <div className="col-md-4">
          <label htmlFor="inputEmail4" className="form-label">District</label>
          <select className="form-select" value={selectedDistrict} onChange={handleDistrict} aria-label="Select District" >
            <option value="Select District">Select District</option>
            <option value={Data.data[0].DISTRICT}>{Data.data[0].DISTRICT}</option>
          </select>
        </div>

       <div className="col-md-4">
          <label htmlFor="inputPassword4" className="form-label">Assembly Constituency Number & Name.</label>
          <select className="form-select" value={selectedConstituencyNameandNumber} onChange={handleConstituencyNameandNumber} aria-label="Select Assembly Constituency Number & Name." >
            <option style={{"display": "block"}} value="Select Assembly Constituency Number & Name.">Select Assembly Constituency Number & Name.</option>
            {selectedDistrict && acBooth.map((acBooth, index) => (
              <option key={index} value={acBooth['AC No & Name']}>{acBooth['AC No & Name']}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>

       <div className="col-md-4">
          <label htmlFor="inputEmail4" className="form-label">Booth No.</label>
          <select className="form-select" value={selectedBoothNumber} onChange={handleBoothNumber} aria-label="Select Booth No." >
            <option value="Select Booth No.">Select Booth No.</option>
            {selectedDistrict && partNumber.map((item, index) => (
              <option key={index} value={item["Part No"]}>{item["Part No"]}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
```

This is the code for 3 drop down menu. I want to execute a function which takes two parameter from the selected options in drop down menu and then display the output in the blank text field whose code is given below.

```
 <div className="col-md-4">
          <label htmlFor="inputEmail4" className="form-label">Booth Name</label>
         
          <input type="text" disabled className="form-control" value={boothName} onChange={()=>{
            const newName = getBoothName(selectedConstituencyNameandNumber, selectedBoothNumber);
            setBoothName(newName);
            console.log(newName);
          }} id="inputUID" />
        </div>
```

These are the function which I have written. It is working properly in the backend but I am unable to get the output in frontend.

```
  const getBoothName = (acNo, partNo) => {
  const boothName = Data.data.filter((item) => {
      return item["AC No & Name"] === acNo && item["Part No"] === partNo
  })
  return boothName[0]["Part Name English"]
}
  const [selectedDistrict, setSelectedDistrict] = useState('');
  const [selectedConstituencyNameandNumber, setSelectedConstituencyNameandNumber] = useState('');
  const [selectedBoothNumber, setSelectedBoothNumber] = useState('');

  const handleDistrict = (e) => {
    setSelectedDistrict(e.target.value);
   }
  const handleConstituencyNameandNumber = (e) => {
    setSelectedConstituencyNameandNumber(e.target.value);
  }
  const handleBoothNumber = (e) => {
    setSelectedBoothNumber(e.target.value);
  }
```

A help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The onChange function of your Input Textfield should be on the 3rd Select field. After that on change of your third dropdown it will `setBoothName(newName)` and your value will be set in the input textfield.

```
<div className="col-md-4">
  <label htmlFor="inputEmail4" className="form-label">
    Booth No.
  </label>
  <select
    className="form-select"
    value={selectedBoothNumber}
    onChange={handleBoothNumber}
    aria-label="Select Booth No."
  >
    <option value="Select Booth No.">Select Booth No.</option>
    {selectedDistrict &&
      partNumber.map((item, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={item["Part No"]}>
          {item["Part No"]}
        </option>
      ))}
  </select>
</div>
```

Change `handleBoothNumber` function in your code like this

```
const handleBoothNumber = (e) => {
  setSelectedBoothNumber(e.target.value);
  setBoothName(getBoothName(selectedConstituencyNameandNumber, selectedBoothNumber));
}
```

Comment: This time, it's a new error. Can you please help??

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')
    at handleBoothNumber (IdCardForm.js:72:1)
    at onChange (IdCardForm.js:210:1)

Comment: still not working

Comment: if possible can you please help. I can share my screen through anydesk.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: Btw Really appreciate your efforts